# Get UTC time from seconds

Tags: c, linux, time, utc

I have a function that gets the time in a `struct tm` and converts it to a certain protocol. I have as the `UTC` time in seconds since 1/1/1970 and I wonder if there is a method similiar to `localtime()` that gets as input a value in seconds since 1/1/1970 and returnes the `UTC` time in `struct tm`.

Comment: Yes. Is there anything else we can help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the UTC time in the format of a struct tm*

[`gmtime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html) does the job.